# How does pointer in function work at this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, variable-assignment

```
int  f_point(int kek,int *lol) {
    *lol *= *lol;
    return kek;
}

int main {  
     int x;
     std::cin >> x;
     int *adress_of_x = &x;
     int a,b = f_point(x,&x); //how does it work?
     std::cout << a << LINE_JUMP;
     std::cout << b << LINE_JUMP;
}
```

For example, if I give 2 to program then I will get 0 and 2. Why?

Comment: The variable a is not initialized so the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: WTH is `LINE_JUMP`?? A macro definition for `std::endl`? What would you expect `a` to contain. The initialization is only done for `b`.

Comment: Vlad, should not function return two values (one from "return" and one from pointer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  int a,b = f_point(x,&x); //how does it work?
> ```

The variable declaration leaves `a` uninitialized and initializes `b` from the result of `f_point(x,&x);`.

Since it's an uninitialized variable, accessing the value of `a` in the

```
 std::cout << a << LINE_JUMP;
```

statement leads to undefined behavior of your program. Having an output of `0` is just one of any possibilities (including your fridge explodes unexpectedly or little demons flying out of your nostrils).

Answer (score 2):

`b = f_point(x,&x)`  in this statement value of first parameter is `2`.
Your function is not changing the value of first parameter and returns the same value.

Your are passing first parameter *by value* so it has no relation with the updated value of `x`. Variable `a` is uninitialized, so it is taking a garbage value.